# How was the double slit experiment predicted in theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, wavefunction-collapse

I am interested to know how theorists made predictions for the double slit experiment.

The issue is this: You'd think that for a screen at $x=L$, the interference pattern is given by $|\psi(x=L,t)|^2$. It seems straightforward. But wait, what is $t$?

The QM framework is designed for experiments which happen at a *chosen* time. But a screen just doesn't fit that kind of experiment.

I would be most interested in an answer which is supported by a reference to a peer-reviewed paper, so that it is clearly an accepted answer rather and not just a personal take.

This question was originally closed for being unfocused. I will state the question as clearly as possible again below. If it is still unfocused, maybe someone can help me to improve it. Question:

> How were the results of the double slit experimented predicted? Ideally the answer would be supported by a reference to an original paper which details the theory to be compared to experiment. If this does not exist, it would still be interesting to find a reference to any paper in a trustworthy journal which makes a prediction for the experiment.

---

**Response to anna v's approach in her comment; commentary on what a working approach would look like**

The reader might argue: just integrate $|\psi|^2$, the signal will be

$$\int\limits_{t_\mathrm i}^{t_\mathrm f}|\psi(x=L,t)|^2\,\mathrm dt$$

where the times $t_\mathrm i$ and $t_\mathrm f$ are the beginning and end times of the experiment. But $|\psi(x,t)|^2$ is only meant to be integrated over positions, not times (its units make this clear). So even when $\psi$ is normalized, this integral doesn’t give a normalized position distribution; the integral over the detector area can exceed 1*. And in fact it may not converge *at all* if the upper bound is taken to $t_\mathrm f=\infty$, which corresponds to the physical limit that one leaves the screen to record points for a long time (compared to the typical arrival time); this is in fact the expected regime! If the integral over all times is infinite, it of course cannot be normalized at all. This is a common case: for a gaussian wave packet we have $\int_{0}^{\infty}|\psi|^2 dt = \infty$, I believe for any $x$ though it's been a while since looking into that. And thanks to the integral over time it also no longer even has units of a probability distribution in position, which is what we seek.

To fix these issues: We may multiply by a constant which has its units chosen so that the result has the right units. We may also introduce a maximal cutoff time for our integral, and additionally normalize it, if possible, to save the proposal. Our proposal now follows less and less directly from the postulates of QM and more from our "fixes". At this point, it is not straightforward that the result will agree with experiment. Maybe we could fiddle with the values of the unit conversion constant or choose the integration bounds to get just about the right result. But even if we succeed, have we really made a prediction, or just calibrated our parameters to fit this particular experiment?

*In order to account for the probability that the particle does not hit the screen *at all*, so that it "escapes", it may be desirable that we generalize to Probability(escape) + Integral(screen distribution) = 1. Still we need the distribution to integrate to a number between 0 and 1.

**Some thoughts of mine on this question**

The intuition to integrate over time comes, I think, from the hope that $|\psi|^2$ acts not only as a position probability density, but also as a probability density in time, so that integrating over time gives the probability of finding the particle in that time interval. However, $|\psi|^2$ does not give a valid distribution in that sense, for the reasons above. It generally cannot be normalized in $t$, it is just not meant for that purpose.

We would have an answer if we had access to a joint distribution, let's call it $\Pi(y,z,t)$, so that $\Pi(y,z,t)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dt$ is the probability for a particle to arrive at position $(x=L,y,z)$ on the screen at a time $t$. Any such valid distribution would integrate to at most 1 in all variables. Then the interference pattern intensity in the region $[y, y+dy],[z,z+dz]$ can properly be expressed as
$$\int\limits_{t_\mathrm i}^{t_\mathrm f}\Pi(y,z,t)\,\mathrm dt$$
where $t_\mathrm f$ is the time at which the experiment stopped looking for the particles. Since the time spent recording data is much larger than a typical arrival time, one might reasonably take $t_\mathrm f=\infty$, and for any valid probability density $\Pi(y,z,t)$ this will converge to less than $1$. Certainly the experimentalist can choose not to turn off her/his device so the distribution must integrate to less than $1$ for arbitrarily large $t$.

So, what is the correct $\Pi(y,z,t)$ in Quantum Mechanics? So far it seems there is no generally accepted answer. In fact Muga and Leavens have a long article summarizing many proposed, inequivalent approaches to arrival times (paper [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/223087825_Arrival_time_in_quantum_mechanics)). Having read through these approaches and more, the most credible one in my view is the one proposed by Bohmian Mechanics.

I don't have an issue with Bohmian Mechanics, but I don't think that the original explanations of the double slit invoked it. So how did people explain this, historically?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105678/discussion-on-question-by-doublefelix-can-the-double-slit-experiment-be-predicte).

Comment: The are fogetting that the longer yoyu do the experimen, the more partciels will ht the screen The total number of particles that hitthe screen  is $|\psi(x)|^2 v (t_f-t_1)$ where $v=k/m$ is the speed.

Answer (score 0):

In double slit experiment we don't have only wave, there are also particles(when they hit detector). So from my opinion you can't have only wave function. Wave function can give you range for detection pattern and probability where particle will hit detector follow normal distribution.

Comment: I am looking for a mathematical solution to the problem. I don't completely disagree with what you've written, but it doesn't provide an answer as of the current writing.